# Windows 8.1 - remote desktop stopped connecting

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop

Can anyone offer an explanation why remote desktop would stop connecting from a windows 8.1 client.

I have two laptops (both running windows 8.1 Pro). One has suddenly stopped connecting to our remote server. With a typically unhelpful Microsoft error message, It just says

```
This computer can't connect to the remote computer.
Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator".
```

It's not even getting as far as checking the credentials as I can put any garbage in for the password and get the same response.

The other laptop still connects fine.

Both laptops are logged in with the same user account (local admin on both), connected to the internet via the same (wired) router, are up to date with all windows updates, and so far as I can tell have the same software installed, with nothing new having been installed recently.